# Get href content and replace() in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, replace, undefined

I'm trying to get the "href" content of an anchor tag but I can't. Here I post the code:

HTML content:

```
<li class="selected"><a href="#featured">Feat.</a></li>

<div class="page"><a href="#2">2</a></div>
```

JQuery content:

```
$('.page a').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          //the following replace works fine
          var t = this.href.replace(/http:\/\/.*\/#(.*)/, '$1');
          var p = $(this).closest('div');
          //the following replace didn't work
          var s = $('li.selected a').href.replace(/http:\/\/.*\/#(.*)/, '$1');
});
```

I want that when you click on `<a href='#2'>2</a>` you get `var s = "featured"`. But when I use the previous function it return a undefined value. What's wrong in my function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('li.selected a')` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so it doesn't have an `href` property. Change to:

```
var s = $('li.selected a')[0].href.replace(/http:\/\/.*\/#(.*)/, '$1');
```

Comment: Side note that to modify attributes of jQuery objects, you can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2). The DOM object's `href` property is simpler and faster, though.

Comment: There's also a difference. `.attr('href')` gets the literal href attribute from the DOM, but `.href` gets the resolved URL.

Comment: @Barmar Good to know it!